# Magento Price filter "from x to unlimited"

Tags: magento

I know how Magento can filter prices by Range.

But, how can I filter for products with price X and higher? I dont want a top limit for the Price.

If you need a further explanation please ask.

A little example to be more clear.
I want be able to add a price filter which supports for example from 200$ up to 800 000$

Comment: do you want this to work like a regular Layered Navigation filter? So, in the filter block in the left column (typically)

Comment: Are you trying to do this programmatically or through some interface on the site?

Comment: i know it is not possible over the existant interface. So i search for a programmatically way.

And yes Jonathan Day, it should work like a regular Layered Navigation filter

Answer (score 2):

Ugly answer: in order to apply a limit to price fields you need to revert to the (almost) plain old SQL.
First a little background.

Product collections use pre-calculated values from the price index table `catalog_product_index_price`.

The index table gets joined in using the table alias `price_index` when `addPriceData()`is called on the collection.

Lets assume we have a product collection and a variable containing the lower price limit initialized as follows:

```
$lowerPriceLimit = 200;

/** @var $products Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection */
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('name');
```

You probably want to test against the field `final_price` because that is the value that will be used when a product is purchased (as compared to `price`, `special_price` or others).

This is an example how add the condition:

```
// Join the price_index table
$products->addPriceData();

// Apply price limit
$products->getSelect()->where('price_index.final_price >= ?', $lowerPriceLimit);
```

Here is an alternative. If you want to do it a little more *the Magento way* (that is use more complicated methods), use this:

```
$customerGroupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
$websiteId = Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId();

$products->joinField(
    'filter_price',                // field alias
    'catalog/product_index_price', // table
    'final_price',                 // real field name
    'entity_id=entity_id',         // primary condition
    array(                         // additional conditions
        'website_id' => $websiteId,
        'customer_group_id' => $customerGroupId,
        'final_price' => array('gteq' => $lowerPriceLimit)
    )
);
```

If you also use `addPriceData()` in this second way you will end up with a double inner join on the price index, but it will still work...

All rather low level, but on the up side of things, at least this is still pretty standard compliant SQL, so it should be rather upward compatible, too.

Maybe you can combine this with the answer from Sylvain to make it part of the layered navigation price range filter.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example on how you can create your own filter with some explanation. We use it to provide a filter for our free products, you will need to adapt to your situation.
You need to overwrite the class `Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Price`

In the code below, `$index` define the index in the price range filter. If you have 4 price range, index 1 is the first and index 4 in the last one. `$range` is the range of price, if you have a range = 100 and an index = 1, the price range will be between 1 to 100. If you have index = 4 and range = 1000, you will get product price range from 3000 USD to 4000 USD (USD is an example).

The code may be improved, you could for example do in the method `_getItemsData()`, `$data = parent::_getItemsData()`, then use $data to make your changes

```
class MyCompany_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Price extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Price {
    protected function _getItemsData()
    {
    $range      = $this->getPriceRange();
    $dbRanges   = $this->getRangeItemCounts($range);

    // Display an item Free Products to allow to select only them in the layer navigation block
    if($count = $this->_getResource()->getCountFreeProducts($this)){
        $data[] = array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Free Products'),
            'value' => '1,1',
            'count' => $this->_getResource()->getCountFreeProducts($this) );    
    }else{
        $data = array();
    }

    foreach ($dbRanges as $index=>$count) {
        $data[] = array(
            'label' => $this->_renderItemLabel($range, $index),
            'value' => $index . ',' . $range,
            'count' => $count,
        );
    }

    return $data;
    }
}
```

Comment: this is a good explaination of adding an filter, but i dont see here, how i can add a filter which starts at 1009 and ends for example at 500 000.

Answer (score 0):

if you want like this

under $50

$50 - $99(5)

$100 - $199(3)

$200 - $299(10)

$300 - $499(2)

$500 - $699(17)

$700 - $899(1)

$900 or above(12)

You can get help from http://www.codegyan.com/2012/01/06/customize-filter-price-range-in-magento/

Answer (score 0):

I use this code below for my filter.phtml. hope this help.

```
<?php 
    $getLabel = $_item->getLabel();
    if (strpos($getLabel, 'price')!== false) :?>
        <a class="multi-select unselected" href="<?php echo $this->urlEscape($_item->getUrl()) ?>">

            <?php 
            $getValue = $_item->getValue();
                $fitlerPrices = str_replace('-', ' - ', $getValue);


                $file = basename($fitlerPrices); 

                $parts = explode("-", $file); 
                $getCurency = Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode())->getSymbol();
                $priceBefore = $getCurency . number_format($parts[0], 0);
                $priceAfter = $getCurency . number_format($parts[1], 0); ?>
                <?php
                    if($i == $count){
                        //Last Item
                        echo '<span class="price">' . $priceBefore . ' and Above</span>';
                    }elseif($i <= 1){
                        //First Item 
                        echo '<span class="price">Under ' . $priceAfter . '</span>';
                    }else{
                         echo '<span class="price">' . $priceBefore . ' - ' .$priceAfter . '</span>';
                    }
                ?>

            </a>
    <?php else :?>

        <a class="multi-select unselected" href="<?php echo $this->urlEscape($_item->getUrl()) ?>"><?php echo $_item->getLabel(); ?></a>
    <?php endif?>
```

Comment: Code only answers arent encouraged as they dont provide much information for future readers please provide some explanation to what you have written